# Calculate packet loss with random transmission times and TTL

Tags: probability, percentages

If I have random lag times from `a=0.1` to `b=0.3` and a time to live (TTL) of `x=0.25`, what would be the packet loss in per cent?

Ok so basically I have packets that arrive in `Random [a,b]` time, if that random value is greater than `x` the packet gets lost and doesn't arrive.

What is the probability of a packet to arrive?

Comment: what do you mean by this last expression? you are taking the limit of which function? and what does "$0$ else $1$" mean?

Comment: I guess a sum would have been a better. I have really no idea how to approach this.

Comment: The expression you wrote doesn't make sense. Please edit your question and explain it in writing.

Comment: I edited the question and explained it a bit more in detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are taking a uniform random number in the range $[0.1,0.3]$ and asking the chance that it is less than $0.25$.  You win in $0.25-0.1=0.15$ of the range of $0.3-0.1=0.2$, so the chance is $\frac {0.15}{0.2}=0.75$

Answer (score 0):

Assume that the time delay has a uniform distribution, then the probability of packet loss is given by the probability of the time delay being larger than 0.25.

This can be easily computed as $$(0.25-0.1)* \frac{1}{0.3-0.1} = 0.15*5 = 0.75$$

i.e, probability of packet arrival is $75\%$, and the probability of packet loss is  $25\%$